# $group with $map not working properly in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongodb aggregation, i have a collection

```
{
"_id":60ab3312623b0108338a9601,
"items":[{"type":"Tshirt","price":300,"quantity":2}],
"orderId":"ORD189",
"from":"abc",
"to":"xyz",
"createdAt":2021-05-24T05:01:06.960Z,
"__v":0,
"tracking":null
}
```

I want to find the count of orders per day and totalPrice of items like

```
{_id: {date:24, month:05, year:2021}, count: 1, totalPrice: 600}
```

I used aggregations like below

```
db.getCollection("orders").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$group" : { 
                "_id" : { 
                    "date" : { 
                        "$dayOfMonth" : "$createdAt"
                    }, 
                    "month" : { 
                        "$month" : "$createdAt"
                    }, 
                    "year" : { 
                        "$year" : "$createdAt"
                    }
                }, 
                "count" : { $sum : 1},
                "totalPrice" : { 
                    $sum: {
                        $map: {
                            "input" :"$items",
                            "as":"item",
                            "in":{
                                $multiply: ["$item.price", "$item.quantity"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

It is giving me the following result

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "date" : NumberInt(24), 
        "month" : NumberInt(5), 
        "year" : NumberInt(2021)
    }, 
    "count" : 1.0, 
    "totalPrice" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

If I use unwind am not able to get the proper count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to correct `totalPrice` calculation,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `items` and do multiplication of `price` and `quantity`, this will return array of total
- `$sum` to get total of above total

```
"totalPrice": {
  $sum: {
    $sum: {
      $map: {
        input: "$items",
        in: {
          $multiply: ["$$this.price", "$$this.quantity"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N8C7bucYSLv)